# Why is openpyxl not finding defined names scoped to worksheet?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, worksheet

I am trying to retrieve the `defined names` scoped to a particular `worksheet` in an Excel file using `worksheet.defined_names`, however this always returns an empty dict.
I have, of course, confirmed that my Excel file does indeed have a defined name scoped to the worksheet in question, and that I am accessing the correct worksheet.

When switching the scope of the `defined name` in question to the `workbook` (i.e. global scope) and using `workbook.defined_names` everything works and I am getting the dict I expected.

**EDIT**

To clarify, when setting the defined names' scope to `worksheet`, they don't show up at all, even when using `workbook.defined_names`.

**EDIT - END**

I have checked the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/defined_names.html#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CDefined%20names%20are%20descriptive%20text,of%20cells%20across%20different%20worksheets.) but this didn't help as I am using `worksheet.defined_names` as described there.

Does anyone know why I am having this issue?

Comment: Just to clarify, whether the defined name scope is Workbook or a particular sheet it will be in **workbook** under **.defined_names** as  @gendowasright shows in their answer. If required to determine if the scope is workbook or a sheet check the **.localSheetId** (**workbook.defined_names.definedName[X].localSheetId**) . If its **None** the scope is workbook, otherwise for a sheet it will be a number referring to the sheet index (**workbook.sheetnames**)

Comment: Yep, I was still on 3.0.10, I updated to 3.1.0 just now and it has changed per your experience. Therefore the details in the comment seem no longer apply

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for your effort regardless. I have created a new issue for this here:
https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1953